# Kubernetes auth, how can allow public access to a sub-route of an ApiService?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes OIDC-enabled cluster. Also, I have created an `ApiService` to access my app service using the control plane. I do not have any CRD.

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1alpha1.wallet.example.org
spec:
  groupPriorityMinimum: 1000
  group: wallet.example.org
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: my-svc
    namespace: default
    port: 3000
  version: v1alpha1
  versionPriority: 15
```

It is exposed under `kubeAPI` and I can access my service using `Bearer`.
The problem is, that I need public access to some of my REST endpoints in the service. How can I tell Kubernetes to skip this URL to being authenticated via OIDC?

```
I don't talk about Ingress, LB, or NodePort
```

Updated:

I've added the `ClusterRole` & `ClusterRolebinding` :

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: wallet-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "wallet.example.org"
  resources:
  - "*"
  verbs:
  - "*"
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: wallet-rb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: wallet-role
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: system:unauthenticated
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: Group
  name: system:authenticated
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
- kind: Group
  name: system:anonymous
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Also have replaced `wallet.example.org` with `*` too. But no difference.

Response is:

```json
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this RBAC definitions:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: wallet.example.org
rules:
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /apis/wallet.example.org/*
  verbs:
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: wallet.example.org
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: wallet.example.org
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: system:anonymous
```

You can then test access using:

```
kubectl --as=system:anonymous get --raw /apis/wallet.example.org/v1alpha1
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the ```- nonResourceURLs:``` thanks.

Comment: even when it works. I've no success yet.

Comment: Try using User "system:anonymous" instead of Group. It works for me. Also check if you have "--anonymous-auth=true" apiserver flag enabled.

Comment: I've changed the Authorization Mode from ```AlwaysAllow``` to ```RBAC``` and now it seems it's working. I've accepted the answer, please make an upvote to 0. thanks.